# Will Apple reject my iPad app if it doesn't rotate?

Tags: ipad

I made an universal binary and didn't implement any sort of device orientation rotation. Is that a reason for rejection?

Comment: Why is it not rotating? It's a pain for users you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are apps on the store that don't rotate, so unless there's some compelling use case for rotation in your app you'll be ok.